# using logic level converter between my led ring and raspi 4 but it is not working

Tags: pi-4, led

I am working on a small project where I am using a SparkFun Lumini LED Ring. The power supply for the ring is external, connected via its own cable and power adapter.

The link of the datasheet of the Leds: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/d/c/a/4/2/APA_102-2020-256-6.pdf

I am now using this logic level converter between my raspi and led ring. https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-TXS0108E-Converter-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B07NNRS8FS/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=TXS0108E&sr=8-3&th=1

i connected them as following:

3,3V of Raspi to the VA of converter

A1, A2 for the DI and CI for spi connection

another 3,3V pin of Raspi to the OE of the converter

5V of Raspi to the VB of converter

GND of Raspi to GND of converter

DI and CI of led ring to the B1, B2 of the converter

can you help me to find and solve the problem?

Comment: I see no code. Draw a schematic of connections.

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696373/led-ring-is-not-working-using-logic-level-shifter) on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Did you check to see if the LED ring is connected to GND and the +5 V supply voltage properly?

Answer (score 0):

The signal clock of the [APA102](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/d/c/a/4/2/APA_102-2020-256-6.pdf) is 20 MHz, which corresponds to a 25 ns timing (1/20e6 = 50 ns, divided by two for a high and low part of the signal). The maximum data rate of the [TXS0108E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf) is 110 mbps in "push pull" (actively driven high and low) or 1.2 mbs in open drain (just a pull up resistor), which the data sheet translates to 17 or 500 ns timings. Nominally the Pi should be push-pulling, but 25 ns is awfully close to the 17 ns spec. If the Pi isn't driving the signal properly, that only gets worse. Taking that into account some other reports of [poor performance of the TXS108E](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/c4jqfi/txs_bidirectional_level_converter_fails_at/), I would not expect the circuit you've described to work reliably or possibly to work at all.

All that being said, I'm not sure a level shifter is required for driving the LEDs. At least for testing it might be possible to run without one as the signal is output only for driving the LEDs and the APA102 datasheet reports a high signal as 0.7 of VCC, which for 5 V would be 3.5 V - quite close to the 3.3 V signal of the Pi. *As always with running something out of or at the edge of specification, I would not do this for long unless you are comfortable with a risk of damaging the Pi or LEDs.*

An alternatively for the TXS0108E would be a [74AHCT125](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74AHCT125.pdf) or [74AHC125](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74AHC125.pdf) level shifter, as recommended by the [apa102-pi library](https://pypi.org/project/apa102-pi/). These have response times around 1 ns.